# Insert an unique sequence alpha numeric field value in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, unique, sequential

Is it possible to generate an unique 2 character value and insert into a table. The number would start at

1. 0-99
2. letters A-Z
3. letters AA - ZZ
4. possibly A0-A9 to Z0-Z9.

I have no idea how to do this but we need an unique 2 value identifier in this field. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at base 36 conversions, especially if the order you listed in the question isn't a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

One option - not fully coded but I guess enough to get the idea - you might want to extent it if you need sorting of any kind

```
WITH temp (c1) AS (
VALUES ('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),(' '), ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'),('E'), ('F')

)
SELECT t2.c1 || t1.c1 FROM temp t1, temp t2
```

You also might want to review the business requirement because this is a very imited approach in my eyes as the unique values are limited

Comment: So unfortunately the interface that requires this data is also limited. Believe me I do not want a limited solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the end we generated the values in excel and uploaded that to a table. It was not me who built the table so unfortunately I do not have the formula that was used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH 
  N (I) AS (VALUES -9 UNION ALL SELECT I+1 FROM N WHERE I<26)
, S (C) AS (SELECT CASE WHEN I<1 THEN CAST(-I AS CHAR) ELSE CHR(64+I) END FROM N)
SELECT A.C || B.C FROM S A, S B;
```